# GA4 Custom Dimension - Parameters displaying as null

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I'm having some difficulties (aren't we all) with GA4 and custom dimensions. I've needed to capture data using either DOM variables or Custom Javascript variables. These fire fine in GTM and display the relevant information as parameters and values that I have used. I've also added the name of these events and parameters as custom dimensions in GA4. However when in GA4 reports, the event and parameter name are displaying, but the parameter value is showing as null.

Which is frustrating! Anyone have any experience on how to fix this?